# Проблемы при занесении параметров в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Имею такой запрос на php:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pers_users        (name,TypeChakra,int,dam,sp,chak,telo,def,hand_pech,nin,tay,gen,level,img,start,first,klan,login) values('$name','$TypeChakra','$int','$dam','$sp','$chak','$telo','$def','$hand_pech','$nin','$tay','$gen','1','$img','1','1','$klan','$login')")or die(mysql_error());
```

Уже какой раз переписываю запрос, а он все равно не выполняется, и выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int,dam,sp,chak,telo,def,hand_pech,nin,tay,gen,level,img,start,first,klan,login)' at line 1
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне делать с этою бедою?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

так нельзя, у вас имя поля int, что является не очень правильно, потомучто с точки зрения mysql int = integer, т.е. тип данных. варианта 2 либо меняем имя переменной либо читаем мануал к mysql и смотрим примеры как использовать названия полей. если сделать вот так:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pers_users        (`name`,`TypeChakra`,`int`,`dam`,`sp`,`chak`,`telo`,`def`,`hand_pech`,`nin`,`tay`,`gen`,`level`,`img`,`start`,`first`,`klan`,`login`)
```

то все будет работать ;)

**учитесь программировать правильно!**

Comment: Понял, спасибо)